# What is the muiName property and when do I have to set it for Material-UI components?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In the offical material-ui documentation an example for the `AppBar` component [here](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar) looks like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import IconMenu from 'material-ui/IconMenu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
import Toggle from 'material-ui/Toggle';
import MoreVertIcon from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/more-vert';
import NavigationClose from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/close';

class Login extends Component {
  static muiName = 'FlatButton';

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatButton {...this.props} label="Login" />
    );
  }
}

const Logged = (props) => (
  <IconMenu
    {...props}
    iconButtonElement={
      <IconButton><MoreVertIcon /></IconButton>
    }
    targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
    anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top'}}
  >
    <MenuItem primaryText="Refresh" />
    <MenuItem primaryText="Help" />
    <MenuItem primaryText="Sign out" />
  </IconMenu>
);

Logged.muiName = 'IconMenu';

/**
 * This example is taking advantage of the composability of the `AppBar`
 * to render different components depending on the application state.
 */
class AppBarExampleComposition extends Component {
  state = {
    logged: true,
  };

  handleChange = (event, logged) => {
    this.setState({logged: logged});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Toggle
          label="Logged"
          defaultToggled={true}
          onToggle={this.handleChange}
          labelPosition="right"
          style={{margin: 20}}
        />
        <AppBar
          title="Title"
          iconElementLeft={<IconButton><NavigationClose /></IconButton>}
          iconElementRight={this.state.logged ? <Logged /> : <Login />}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AppBarExampleComposition;
```

My questions is about the statements

```
static muiName = 'FlatButton';
```

and

```
Logged.muiName = 'IconMenu';
```

What is `muiName` and when/why do I have to set it? Should it always be set to the name of the top-level component in the `render()` method?

On the same webpage there are examples to `AppBar` where `muiName` is not set.

Answer (score 2):

Answer in [documentation](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/guides/composition/#wrapping-components) is:

`In order to provide the maximum flexibility and performance, we need a way to know the nature of the child elements a component receives. To solve this problem we tag some of our components when needed with a muiName static property.`

Let's check this example:
    // @flow weak

```
import React from 'react';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import Icon from 'material-ui/Icon';

const WrappedIcon = props => <Icon {...props} />;
WrappedIcon.muiName = 'Icon';

export default function Composition() {
  return (
    <div>
      <IconButton>
        <Icon>alarm</Icon>
      </IconButton>
      <IconButton>
        <WrappedIcon>alarm</WrappedIcon>
      </IconButton>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**If you wrapped material-ui component you should set 'muiName' property to wrapper component with value as name of material-ui component you wrapped.**
I hope you understand this phrase :)

Comment: What does "when needed" mean? How should I know when and what to set the property to? Like mentioned: some examples do it, others don't.
As a side note: You've linked the documentation of the beta version `v1.0.0-beta.6`. I should have mentioned that I am using the latest official version `0.19.0`. In that documentation the `muiName` is not mentioned and I missed that. Sorry.

Comment: @Joerg i think this feature with muiName static property will be include in next major version.

If you check link I mentioned before, you can find example with answer.
I will try to update my answer to explain to you.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on the example. So "when needed" translates to "always"? Why don't the other examples set `muiName` then? They all define React components via arrow functions and, thus, wrap Material-UI components in one way or another. However, they do not set `muiName`. I still don't understand.

Comment: If you focus on performance in your app it's better to trust maintainers of material-ui and set muiName for all wrappers of material-ui components...or read code of material-ui and try to find places where `muiName` uses and dig into it.

Comment: Okay, but then again the question, why do those maintainers themselves not set `muiName` in their own examples?

Comment: May be it will be better to open issue on [github](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues) – to get a direct answer on this question.

Answer (score 0):

The example in the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/#wrapping-components) helped me a lot.

Right now with the [v4.8.1](https://material-ui.com), you can add the `muiName` as follow:

```
const WrappedIcon = props => <Icon {...props} />;
WrappedIcon.muiName = Icon.muiName;
```