# Cannot read property 'muiName' of undefined at t.isMuiElement?

Tags: reactjs, dialog, material-ui

I have this problem when browse in chrome.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'muiName' of undefined at t.isMuiElement (reactHelpers.js:31)
```

when I use `<List> <ListItem>` in `<DialogContent>` that error is showed.

```
<DialogContent> 
  <List>
     <ListItem> <ListItemText primary='Minimum booking notice: 24 hours in advance' /> </ListItem>            
     <ListItem> <ListItemText primary='Tour costs: Tour costs and what inclusion or exclusion is listed on the itinerary for each tour. No refunds will be given for unutilized services.'/></ListItem>
   </List>
</DialogContent>
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize to use `muiName`

[What is the muiName property and when do I have to set it for Material-UI components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45958490/what-is-the-muiname-property-and-when-do-i-have-to-set-it-for-material-ui-compon/)

```
const DialogContentList = (props) => (
  <List>
  <ListItem> 
    <ListItemText primary='Minimum booking notice: 24 hours in advance' />
  </ListItem> 
  </List>
);
DialogContentList.muiName = 'IconMenu';
class Footer extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state= {
          open: false
        }     
      }
      render() {
<DialogContentList />
      }
    }
    export default withMobileDialog()(withStyles(styles)(Footer));
```

I found the reason for the problem.In the past, I used `material-ui` that is ***deprecated***.so use `material-ui/core/` instead of it.
before i use

`import List, { ListItem, ListItemText } from '@material-ui/core/List';`
and now I use this

```
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem'; 
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
```

My problem **solved**.

Answer (score 6):

This happened to me because I set the variant of the `TextField` to an unknown value:

```
<TextField variant="unkownVariant"
```

While the `variant` [prop](https://mui.com/api/text-field/#main-content) by default only accepts the following type: `'filled' | 'outlined' | 'standard'`

To fix it, simply change the variant to the correct type again.

```
<TextField variant="filled"
```

Comment: yeah same, i did variant="Standard" (the s should've been lower case)