# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'muiName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

i am trying to render the elements of the array inside a custom card component inside a grid. but when the page opens it freezes and the console displays ***"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'muiName' of undefined"***

**the custom component**

```
LookupMedication = (medicationName) => {
    return (
      <Grid xs={3} item>
        <Card
          style={{
            width: "18em",
            marginBottom: "2em",
          }}
        >
          <CardActionArea>
            <CardMedia
              style={{
                height: "8em",
              }}
              image={Meds}
              title={medicationName}
            />
            <CardContent>
              <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                {medicationName}
              </Typography>
              <TextField
                fullWidth
                label="Amount Available"
                variant="outline"
                type="number"
              ></TextField>
            </CardContent>
          </CardActionArea>
          <CardActions>
            <Button
              fullWidth
              style={{
                color: "white",
                backgroundColor: "#1818",
              }}
              startIcon={<PostAddIcon />}
            >
              Add
            </Button>
          </CardActions>
        </Card>
      </Grid>
    );
  };
```

**the map function**

```
<Grid container>
          {this.medications.map((medication) =>
            this.LookupMedication(medication)
          )}
        </Grid>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Show code that implements muiName

Answer (score 0):

## You need to add muiName to your component

Underneath LookupMedication just add the code.

```
LookupMedication.muiName = 'Grid';
```

For more detail about muiName check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45958490/what-is-the-muiname-property-and-when-do-i-have-to-set-it-for-material-ui-compon/)